# Why C# does not require explicit casting for convert Long To Double?

Tags: c#, casting

At first, sorry for my bad english.
I have fragment of code:

```
long x = 9223372036854775807L;
double f = x;
Console.WriteLine(x);           
Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Output is:

```
9223372036854775807
9,22337203685478E+18
```

I'm not getting any errors while compiling and execution this code.
We have a loss of precision while converting Long to Double. 
Why C# does not require explicit casting in that case ?

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you mean explicit cast?

Comment: The language was designed like that. What do you want to hear?

Answer (score 14):

The language has some implicit conversion built into it.

The following table is from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), which is why you are allowed to assign the value without an explicit cast or conversion:

```
From        To
===============================================================================
sbyte       short , int, long, float, double, or decimal
byte        short , ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal
short       int , long, float, double, or decimal
ushort      int , uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal
int         long , float, double, or decimal
uint        long , ulong, float, double, or decimal
long        float , double, or decimal
char        ushort , int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal
float       double
ulong       float , double, or decimal
```

And in the documentation it states (emphasis mine):

> Precision but not magnitude might be lost in the conversions from
>   int, uint, long, or ulong to float and **from long or ulong to double**.

Comment: I don't like this. Strongly typed languages should not have possibility of losing pressure without explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
long x = 9223372036854775807L;
decimal f = x;
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(f);
```