# Convert long to double

Tags: c#

Having

```
long number = 1475;
```

Is there any difference between

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(number);
```

and

```
double d = (double)number;
```

Comment: [Nope.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1579) (Note that you can just write `double d = number;` as there's an implicit conversion from `long` to `double`.)

Comment: Lol double d ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet, why did you put your answer as a comment and not as a proper answer?

Comment: Is `long` a 64 bit type in C#? If so, then note that the conversion to `double` is lossy for large numbers.

Comment: Double is 16 bytes and longs are only 8...

Comment: "Cast when it's really a type of double, Convert when it's not a double but you want it to become one."

Comment: Convert can do more specific operations while converting than directcast due to the specific constructors. Here is a good post you can read more about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394032/difference-between-casting-and-using-the-convert-to-method

Comment: @Botonomous: in which case, for example, 2**53 + 1 will not convert exactly to a double. (It will round to an even).

Comment: @kiziu: When the answer is basically just a link, it doesn't feel worth having as a full answer...

Comment: @kiziu: i'm not sure if this is a new question, there are already similars/duplicates like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860416/why-c-sharp-does-not-require-explicit-casting-for-convert-long-to-double) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394032/difference-between-casting-and-using-the-convert-to-method).

Comment: @kiziu probably because this question won't last long here. (duplicate, lack of research, etc...)